# PopupWindow's size in px or dip?

Tags: android, size, popupwindow

From [PopupWindow Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#PopupWindow%28int,int%29) :

> public PopupWindow (int *width*, int *height*)
>
> Added in API level 1
>   Create a new empty, non focusable popup window. The dimension of the window must be passed to this constructor.
>
> The popup does not provide any background. This should be handled by the content view.
>
> **Parameters**
>   *width*   the popup's width
>   *height*  the popup's height

***Question:*** does the `width` and `height` is in pixels (px) or Density-independent Pixels (dip) ?

***Bonus Question:*** how can the `PopupWindow` achieve Multiple Screen Support ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width and height parameters are specified in pixels (px). If you want to convert to density independent pixels (dp), you can use the following:

```
TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 65, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Where 65 is replaced by the number of density-independent pixels. This returns the number of pixels which you can then give to PopupWindow.